# MySQL Inner join using Non unique ID

Tags: mysql, inner-join

i want to update my table from another table using inner join,

Query :

```
UPDATE XYZ INNER JOIN ABC on ABC.Id = XYZ.Id
       SET XYZ.Std = ABC.Std
```

sample data:

Table XYZ

```
           ID                                                          STD

401471  QWERTY1     0   13.381  2013-01-01 00:00:00 2002-06-01 00:00:00 0   0   0   2002-06-01 00:00:00 2005-05-31 00:00:00 
401472  QWERTY2     0   13.488  2013-01-04 00:00:00 2002-06-01 00:00:00 0   0   0   2002-06-01 00:00:00 2005-05-31 00:00:00 
401473  QWERTY3     0   13.465  2013-01-07 00:00:00 2002-06-01 00:00:00 0   0   0   2002-06-01 00:00:00 2005-05-31 00:00:00
```

Table ABC

```
ID                                              STD Q  W

QWERTY1 2002-06-01 00:00:00 2005-05-31 00:00:00 0   0   0
QWERTY2 2002-07-01 00:00:00 2005-06-30 00:00:00 0   0   0
QWERTY3 2002-08-01 00:00:00 2005-07-31 00:00:00 0   0   0
```

The ID is not primary key, and i have more than 1.5 millions records with repeated ID and it repeated because the dates are different.

so my query is not working, as the connections gets lost error 2013, i tried changing the timeout from 600 to 6000, but failed to work as i cannot change the timeout of the db server which is in the cloud.

can anyone tell me , if the query is correct, if yes why is the connection getting lost?

so can i do it in chunks if the query is correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this -**

```
UPDATE XYZ
set XYZ.std = ABC.std
from XYZ inner join ABC on XYZ.id = ABC.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Query might be taking too long to execute that's why you'll be having timeout. You can do it in chunks by setting the range in your query like:

```
UPDATE XYZ 
    INNER JOIN ABC on ABC.Id = XYZ.Id
    SET XYZ.Std = ABC.Std
    WHERE ABC.Id between 1 AND 50000;
```

You can use any other parameter to create chunks, above query is just an example.

Comment: by my id is alphanumeric, so i cant set a range.

Comment: you don't have any integer based `PK` in the table?

Comment: yes there is AI id , but but 1.5million rows, how much range can set?

Comment: can i do this, suppose date is unique for each id, so i can write my query as UPDATE XYZ 
    INNER JOIN ABC on ABC.Id = XYZ.Id and ABC.date=XYZ.date
    SET XYZ.Std = ABC.Std

Comment: Yes you can do this, but still you'll have to set the range to create chunks. It is easy, like I just did with `where` clause. Put range on id `WHERE ABC.Id between 1 AND 50000`, in 2nd query `50001 AND 100000` and so on..

Answer (score 0):

**You can do:**

```
UPDATE XYZ INNER JOIN ABC on ABC.Id = XYZ.Id
       SET XYZ.Std = ABC.Std;
```

in MySQL ([as desicribed here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql) but it's not native ANSI SQL

Do you have set an index on the id column?
You don't have to make it primary but there should be an index.

Comment: my id is alphanumeric and not unique so can i set the index ? it is not possible i suppose.

Comment: you can make following if you have MyISAM or InnoDB
create fulltext index [INDEXNAME] on [TABLENAME] ([COLUMNNAME]);

Comment: CREATE fulltext INDEX RbwIndex ON HistoricalRR (Id);  did this, after that i ran the join query  , still after 30 secs it expires. and should i set index of id in both the tables?

Comment: Yeah you have to set this on both id columns